# Xcode 5: How to align 2 object horizontally using Autolayout in IB?

Tags: ios, xcode, alignment, autolayout

I've got a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`, one sit next to another with a fixed spacing (let say 10pt). The `UILabel's` width may change dynamically. Is it possible to align them centre horizontally like below ?

```
|    @ Abc    |
|             |
|             |

|   @ Abcde   |
|             |
|             |
```

Comment: Which one is label? imageView?. Can u put a clear image

Comment: "@" is the imageView,and "Abc" is the label. *The text of the label may change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both of them in a view like this:

```
|<-- center view  -->|
|  ________________  |
| |       View     | |
| |_______   ______| |
| | Image | | Label| |
| |_______| |______| |
| |________________| |
|                    |
```

Then center the view horizontal. Within the view you need to define constraints for the imageview and the label so that these define the height and width of the view.

**EDIT**
Here are two images that show it works:

[image: Short text]

[image: Longer text]

Comment: Thank you Jens, but what i really is, the left margin of the imageView and the right margin of the label should be in the same distance.

Comment: Yes, you can set the imageview to have 0 leading-distance from the containing view and the label to habe 0 trainling-distance from the containing view. The view will always center - so the view does should have the same distance to both sides and since the imageview and the label are right on the edge of the view they will also have the same distance...

Comment: Yes, it does the trick to centre them, but the image and the label were pulled apart. I tried to adjust the priority, but got no luck.

Comment: Why would the image and the label be pulled apart? Did you set leading and trailing constraints on the view? You shouldn't. Just center it. Then the view should have a width that is just big enough to contain the image and the label.

Comment: Yes, i did add "Center X Alignment" for the container. Since the imageView has 0 leading space to the container, and the label has 0 trailing space to the container. Although I added horizontal spacing between the imageView and the label, both objects were pulled to the edges of the container.

Comment: you can try the set the label.text = @"a";
assume container's width = 200, image's width is 10, the label's width is 10, then there will be 180pt between the both objects.

Comment: I've added two images to show how that it should work. Yellow is the container view.

Comment: Did you get it to work? I could send you the xib example file I created to take the screenshots...

Comment: Yes, I finally figured it out. I works as it should be. What I was confusing myself, is when you use uilabel instead of uiimageview, you will get a different result. (Since, I was trying using 2 uilabel for the test.) But, I have no idea what makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

set UILabel's text alignment to center. then move it to the center of the view so that there's a guid line appear in the center of the UILabel.
sorry, miss understood your mean, 
**updating...**
select both label and image by holding command key then move them to align to the center guid line.

Comment: well... that's static. I mean this is like a detailed viewController, where  "Abc" is the title of the page. And there is always a icon next to the title. So the title will vary.

Comment: @Andre Since the label text will change it's length it's very hard to always center the image and label at the same time unless you caculate the label length and adjust it by code. but you can alway center the label only and put the image on a fix left position of the label.